# Capture multiple images in single interface using AVFoundation

Tags: ios7, avfoundation

I should able to capture multiple images (assume I am capturing passport for id proof) using iOS camera AVFoundation. I mean to say that I should have one interface to capture them one by one and merge them together. Is this possible in iOS, if yes is there any samples available for that.

Any help could be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can't completely get it. You can just take image from photostream one by one, you can take one photo and cut out 2 images, you can use imagepicker to call native camera, where is problem my friend?